# Part of object and texture colour not rendering properly, lamps beside sun does not work

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, objects, color

I am trying to make a photo frame in Blender 2.65. I have not updated it as I feel it is not worth my time, as I very rarely use it (less than once a year). I am also new to Blender and find the user interface and functions/buttons to be very non-intuitive and frustrating. I am using Cycles.

I made the entire frame and a plane to project an image onto as the 'photo', in Rhinoceros then exported it to Blender. At first it rendered fine but then various things weren't working. I stumbled my way to making a properly scaled (for my purposes) frame and UV unwrapped a picture to project onto the plane as the photo in the frame. But, now it won't render properly. Before I UV unwrapped (and used an image as the texture directly), it used to render properly. Now, the top right hand triangular section of the photo only, and not the rest of the frame, will not render properly. If I move the plane forwards or backwards a little, it will not render at all. I do not have a glass in front of it, I couldn't get the glass to be transparent, and so deleted it. I am using a sun as my lamp as none of the other lamp work.

Not only that, for certain images that I use as my 'photo' in the frame, the colours will not render properly. The image I used is this photograph:
https://www.flickr.com/photos/99592065@N06/32565504846/in/album-72157679793623586/

This is what my render looks like:
[image: Incorrectly coloured render]

This is what the render looks like with a different image:
[image: Incorrectly done render]

And this is what the photo *should* look like:
https://www.flickr.com/photos/99592065@N06/34915821210/in/album-72157684732224085/

It wasn't doing it before and I have no idea what is happening and how to fix it.
I have included the blender file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mvioza36kigbsmc/Photo%20frame.blend?dl=0) but the photos are my own and probably won't show when you download the file, so you may need to substitute your own image texture, and, please note, I made the frame in Rhinoceros in centimeters but for some reason, it is in meters in Blender. Not sure if it has anything to do with the other lamps not working. Also I noticed that the colour not rendering properly only occurs with orangey/reddish/yellowish coloured images.

Answer (score 0):

there are several things that went wrong:

1. no lamp other than the sun working:
   thats indeed due to the fact that your frame is 400 m wide. Lamps in Blender (as in the real world) have a quadratic light falloff. so the strength is dependent on the distance from the lamp and your object. if you want to have light from 500m away, the strength must be something like (insert a really high value here).
   The sun doesn't have a falloff in blender as it has no real location, it's just a directional light source.
2. Your image plane is not a plane. it has 8 vertices and the faces overlap each other. 
   go into edit mode with <kbd>TAB</kbd>face select (<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>) select the front face and delete it ( <kbd>X</kbd> > Faces)

Comment: Thanks, I removed the extra face, but any ideas what is causing the unusual colour in the render results?

Comment: do you mean the shadows on the wall? I got rid of them by adding a new sunlamp. I don't understand what went wrong with your sun (maybe an import from rhinoceros that didn't work?) so I didn't include that in my answer.

Comment: Hi bstnhnsl, no I meant why the colour of the photo rendered onto the image plane is off, but I think I figured why, it's because the image I used was converted to CMYK not RGB. That part is all good now, thanks

Comment: that's a problem we can't see if you don't include the textures. ;) if the answer helped, consider accepting it by clicking the check mark so other users with similar problems can find it.